# I need to get connected with MS-SQL by using dplyr R package

Tags: r

I am running MS-SQL Server2008 R2 under the MS SQL Server Management Studio.  I need to use "dplyr" R-project package and MS-SQL. I got some information about how to do it using "RSQLServer" package at https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer    but I have not been able to get it done so far.

I am trying to get the solution for both cases as most Google stuff recommend about it:

Case 1: playing around with the sql.yaml file.

I tried but it did not work in my case. Anyway, I am still trying this solution but I am surrounded and my guess is I will lose very soon.

Case 2: writing the "AW" inside the connection script. [This is the solution that I would like to get done first]

I mean, doing this:

```
library(dplyr)
conDplyr <- RSQLServer::src_sqlserver(server="local", type="sqlserver", user="HA", port: "1433", database = "MydataOne")
```

I do not include "password" because I do not use password in my MS SQL configuration. I consider port "1433" here but my MS-SQL configuration does not have any specific assigned port. It gets one by the time it gets connected). I think this could be some of the problems. I do not know!

Comment: If you're using Windows authentication, note that jTDS can be flaky. Try SQL authentication instead.